# missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Tags: asp.net-mvc, using, using-directives

I'm in the process of writing a small asp.net mvc application that is using the northwind.mdf. When building the solution I get this error:

**Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Order' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Order is a table in the northwind database.

any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill the gap between the SQL table and the .NET application. The reason that you have an Order table in your SQL database doesn't mean that your .NET application knows anything about it. If you are using LINQ To SQL you could [use the VS designer](http://www.asp.net/(S(pdfrohu0ajmwt445fanvj2r3))/learn/mvc/tutorial-10-vb.aspx) to build strongly typed classes based on your relational schema.